# Can we upgrade from SP2013 std to trial key and then switch to Enterprise key later?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, licensing, standard-edition, trial-version

Our development farm (SharePoint 2013 on-premise) is running Standard edition. We have ordered Enterprise license but the key is not available until next month. Our developers need Enterprise feature for their development.

Is it possible to switch our Standard server to Enterprise using Trial key, then switch to Enterprise key later?

Comment: What kind of enterprise feature do they need? Is it for server och client side development?

Comment: Report Server Integration & Power View Integration feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for late update.

First, we get back the old key (a string of numbers and letters) we used to setup this farm as Standard edition. During the process to upgrade the farm to Enterprise, we used the **same key** and it works.

So far we didn't encounter any problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would wait for the month to go by, because even though it is possible to Switch to a trail Version. It's bad practice and **will result in Errors** even though it should not.

If you're willing to suffer the concequences. Go ahead otherwise just complain to get your key faster. When you buy something you shouldn't have to wait a whole month regardless.